# Xamarin iOS objective c binding library Could not create an native instance of the type

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios, xamarin.ios-binding

I created a binding project for Xamarin iOS. 
I succeeded in adding the native library, creating the C# Bindings and resolved all the hundreds of errors I found just to get this error once I try to run the library (in an app on the iPhone simulator):

> Could not create a native instance of the type 'MyNamespace.STPPaymentCardTextField': the native class hasn't been loaded.

Here is the signature of the interface in objective-c:

```
@interface STPPaymentCardTextField : UIControl <UIKeyInput>
```

Here is what I get in my C# iOS binding:

```
[BaseType(typeof(UIControl))]
[Protocol]
interface STPPaymentCardTextField : IUIKeyInput
```

I read [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24316815/7442601) answer and checked the architecture for which my library was built and here is the architecture, taking into consideration that I run it on the iOS simulator:

> are: i386 x86_64

here is the script I use to build the library:

```
all: lib$(TARGET).a

lib$(TARGET)-i386.a:
  $(XBUILD) -project $(PROJECT) -target $(TARGET) -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration Release 
clean build
 -mv $(PROJECT_ROOT)/build/Release-iphonesimulator/lib$(TARGET).a $@


lib$(TARGET).a: lib$(TARGET)-i386.a 
  xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -create -output $@ $^

clean:
  -rm -f *.a *.dll
```

How can I resolve this error please ?

Comment: Hi , do you use `assembly` to load `.a` file in project ,such as : `[assembly: LinkWith ("xxx.a", SmartLink = true, ForceLoad = true)]` ?

Comment: Hello, no I don't do that where should I do that ?

Comment: Okey , you can have a look at here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-c-libraries

Comment: Hi @JuniorJiang-MSFT thanks I went through the docs and I added the file with these two lines only:   using ObjCRuntime;

[assembly: LinkWith("libStripe.a", LinkTarget.ArmV7 | LinkTarget.Simulator| LinkTarget.Arm64, SmartLink = true, ForceLoad = true, Frameworks = "")]

Comment: But after doing that, I had false error messages appearing, the errors are of this type: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/mtouch-errors#MT5211.  Telling me the [Protocol] is miising on some classes whereas it is there in the code and I reference the dll  is up to date.

Comment: And another error message which appeared this message  of the type: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/mtouch-errors#MT5210
The library I'm building depends on several frameworks, one of which is of type "framework.a" but the docs do not precise how to add external frameworks or even how to add more than one framework,
I'm kind of missing something please could you help ?

Comment: Okey , I will check that . Due to time to leave my office , if good idea will update here later :-)

Comment: Hello @JuniorJiang-MSFT any info about how to resolve this please ?

Comment: Hi , whether serveral frameworks call each other ,and the type of them whehter all are `xxx.a` ?

Comment: I mean, the library I'm trying to bind has dependecies on several other frameworks and one of these frameworks is another static library "lib.a" do you know how to add them to the iOS binding ? the docs show only how to add one.

Comment: How about [Linking the dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-c-libraries#linking-the-dependencies) works for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure you have "UIKit" listed under frameworks.
 "Native references ->"properties of native library" -> "frameworks: UIKit"